# What does $var$() mean in bash

Tags: bash

Can someone explain this script in detail.
I understand that it parses output from the ps command and posts the result.
It's unclear how the do while loop collects each entry with this syntax:
`var=$var$()`

Also, `done <<< "$z"`

This is also unclear, redirect ´$z´ to ´done´?

```
#!/bin/bash
z=$(ps aux)
while read -r z
do
   var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3z}');
done <<< "$z"
curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "$var
" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

Comment: command substitution see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html Also there is no `do while` loop in bash, only `while` loop, see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: `<<<` is a `herestring` see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: Sets `var` to the current contents of `var` plus the output of that `awk` one-liner.

Comment: `$3z` - the `z` is strange. Because `z` is empty, it's doing nothing.

Comment: @oivind : I have answered your question, but in the future please don't ask 2 questions in one posting, but create two postings for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is... really poorly written code. The while loop in particular is very misleading, because it only executes once - the `read` reads the header line of the `ps` output, and the `awk` inside it reads the rest of the input. Plus putting `ps` output in a variable first isn't really needed - it's better off being redirected or piped directly. And `$3z` in the awk is strange - I don't know what that `z` is supposed to do, as there's no variable by that name already set.

`var=$var$(...)` sets `var` to the current contents of the variable plus the output of the command in `$()`. But since `var` isn't  already set in this script, it can be written as `var=$(...)`.

See comments in your question for the meaning of `<<<`.

None of that is actually needed, as you can get the same effect with a single pipeline. Rewritten to be more clear and straightforward:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux \
| awk 'NR > 1 { print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3 }' \
| curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

(The `curl` option `--data-binary @-` will read the post data from standard input)

Comment: _But since var isn't already set in this script_  : This is not correct. The assignment is performed in a loop, so `var` is initially empty only on the first iteration.

Comment: @user1934428 There's only one iteration of the loop. The body only executes once.

Comment: Why? `z` holds the output of the `ps` command, so it should be a string with embedded newlines. I had expected the loop to be executed once for each input line.

Comment: @user1934428 See the first paragraph of this answer. The awk call consumes all of standard input after the first line is read by `read`.

Comment: Ah, right you are!!! This is clearly a script which is  still early in the debugging stage.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The first is only string catenation. `x=$y$z` sets `x` to the content of `y`, with the content of `z` appended. Similarily, `x=$y$(z)` sets `x` to the to the content of `y`, with the stdout of the program `z` appended.

(2) `f <<<"$z"` just feeds the content of variable `z` to the stdin of the program `f`. In your case, instead of `f` we have a `while read ....`. Therefore `z` is fed line by line into the `read` statement.

You may ask, why then the command is not simply written as

```
ps aux | while .....
```

The reason is, that bash runs a pipe `f|g` in that `g` is executed in a child process. In your program, it means that the variable `var` would be modified in the child process and the modified variable would not be visible in the `curl` command. By using the auxiliary variable `z`, we can be sure that the `var` in the body of the while-loop is indeed the same as the one used by `curl`.